# Beeline unable to create external hbase table but hive cli can

Tags: hive, hbase, beeline

I have hbase 1.2.3 cluster, and install hive 2.1.1. When I try to create external hbase table through beeline/hiveserver2, I got exception. But if I use hive cli, it is ok. The create statement is as following:

```
create external table hbase_xing(id int, name string) 
   stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
   with serdeproperties ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,f:name")
   tblproperties("hbase.table.name" = "xing");
```

Exception is:

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Fri Jan 06 19:38:24 CST 2017, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=120000, callDuration=128483: row 'xing,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=c3.estarspace.com,16020,1483694415877, seqNum=0

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:271)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:223)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:811)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:303)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:313)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:205)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:742)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:735)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:154)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.createTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:830)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:845)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3992)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:197)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2073)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1744)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1453)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1171)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1166)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:242)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:334)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:347)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=120000, callDuration=128483: row 'xing,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=c3.estarspace.com,16020,1483694415877, seqNum=0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:64)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Call to c3.estarspace.com/192.168.0.13:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Connection to c3.estarspace.com/192.168.0.13:16020 is closing. Call id=12, waitTime=3
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.wrapException(RpcClientImpl.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:32651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Connection to c3.estarspace.com/192.168.0.13:16020 is closing. Call id=12, waitTime=3
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.cleanupCalls(RpcClientImpl.java:1037)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.close(RpcClientImpl.java:844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.run(RpcClientImpl.java:572)
) (state=08S01,code=1)
```

I put hbase.zookeeper.quorum into the hive-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Track the source code, It looks like something wrong when HIVE to call HBASE Client to call the region server.

This problem seems only exist in HBase 1.2.3. Upgrade to HBase 1.2.4, HIVE function corrently.